# Image Tool for HDD - bootable from USB device

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, disk-image

i am search a image tool for hdd

**Requirements**

1. Start from the USB device
2. Multiple images on the usb device (choose image to copy)
3. Clone image to HDD

Our current image is a ".imgc" file (HDD Raw Copy Tool) the copy tool is only available on windows and is not booting from usb-device.

Answer (score 1):

Many tools exist.
These are ISO you can convert to USB stick

Clonezilla  (drbl ISO comes with clonezilla) www.clonezilla.org

This option is probably a bit simpler if you just want to clone to one hdd at a time.

DRBL:  drbl.sourceforge.net

1. Boot into linux live
2. mount your hdd to /home/partimage
3. start drbl (icon)
4. Static IP 192.168.0.1
5. su terminal
6. dcs

The dcs command is a menu based system for deciding what mode the system should be in.  DRBL even allows you to PXE boot clients to do multiple computers at once.